# why my code is getting this message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c

I am trying to write this c program in Linux but when I run the program it executes half of the code and then bash shows this message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    char stName[30];
    int info[3];
    int showinfo()
   {
    printf("The name of the student is %s\n",stName);
    printf("The age of the student is %d",info[0]);
    int i = 1;
    while(i<4)
    {
     printf("The marks in subject %d is %d",i,info[i]);
     i++;
    }
   }
    int getinfo()
   {
    printf("Enter name of the student: ");
    gets(stName);
    printf("enter the age of the student %s : ",stName);
    gets(info[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
     printf("Enter the marks in subjet %d",i);
     gets(info[i]);
    }
    return 0;
   }
    getinfo();
    showinfo();
    
}
```

The output is like this:

```
Enter name of the student: Keshav
enter the age of the student Keshav : 20
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: since the array starts at 0 and has a length of 3 the last index wiill be 2. But you try to access index 3. That is your out of bounds I guess.

Comment: @TheFool execution does not reach that line, otherwise `Enter the marks...` would be printed twice

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets` (never be used) to read non-string types. Also the type is wrong, `gets` takes `char *` as the argument type. And C doesn't support using nested functions

Comment: It isn't valid C -- C doesn't permit nested functions. Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: long story short, `gets` tries to write the input string into address pointed by `info[0]` which has not been initialized and thus contains garbage value

Comment: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: @hyde I mean with a given set of enabled warnings, which allowed a successful compilation in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a great number of small problems. First `"ISO C forbids nested functions"`, you should declare/define `void showinfo()` and `char *getinto()` above `main()`, not in it. Next, you must ensure when you loop, you do not attempt to write beyond the bounds of your arrays. Next, see: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) It is so insecure and so prone to exploit by buffer-overrun it has been completely removed for the C11 library.

When writing `showinfo()`, it being nothing but an output routine, there is no need to have that function return a value. Change the return type to `void` to make that clear. Since you are now declaring the functions outside of `main()`, you will need to pass the variables needed in that function as parameters, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 128   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NFOC   4

void showinfo (const char *stName, int *info)
{
    printf ("\nThe name of the student is %s\n"
            "The age of the student is %d\n\n", stName, info[0]);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < NFOC; i++)
        printf ("  The marks in subject %2d is %2d\n", i, info[i]);
}
```

(**note:** you only need a single `printf()` call to output both lines of text. Adjacent literal character string are concatenated during compilation)

and for `getinfo()`,

```
char *getinfo (char *stName, int *info)
{
    fputs ("Enter name of the student: ", stdout);
    if (fgets (stName, MAXC, stdin) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    stName[strcspn (stName, "\r\n")] = 0;   /* trim trailing \n from end of stName */
    
    printf ("enter the age of the student %s  : ", stName);
    if (scanf ("%d", &info[0]) != 1)
        return NULL;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < NFOC; i++) {
        printf ("Enter the marks in subjet %d : ", i);
        if (scanf ("%d", &info[i]) != 1)
            return NULL;
    }
    return stName;
}
```

Above the `stName` arrays along with the `info` array are passes as parameters to the function, as well as to `showinfo()` above. Here the return of `stName` is for convenience allowing you to use the function within the `printf` variable list if desired. It returns `NULL` to indicate failure in collecting the input.

`main()` now simplifies to:

```
int main (void)
{
    char stName[MAXC];
    int info[NFOC];
    
    getinfo (stName, info);
    showinfo (stName, info);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running your program and providing input when prompted, you would receive the following output:

```
$ ./bin/nested
Enter name of the student: John Q. Student
enter the age of the student John Q. Student  : 21
Enter the marks in subjet 1 : 88
Enter the marks in subjet 2 : 87
Enter the marks in subjet 3 : 92

The name of the student is John Q. Student
The age of the student is 21

  The marks in subject  1 is 88
  The marks in subject  2 is 87
  The marks in subject  3 is 92
```

---

**Enable Warnings**

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. All other compilers will have similar options. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

Look things over and let me know if  you have further questions.